# Invalid Input syntax for type interval postgres

Tags: postgresql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Sql code which should pull the active data from the table by using an interval function.

```
Select * from contacts
Where systemmodstamp::date > (current_date - interval '${p_active_data_days_interval} day')::date
```

The `p_active_data_days_interval` is used as a parameter and the declared value is set to "30" in setting tab. systemmodstamp is a field of type timestamp without time zone.

When previewing the data resulting an error:

> invalid input syntax for type interval: "${p_active_data_days_interval} day"

Comment: Apparently `${p_active_data_days_interval}` is **not** replaced with the parameter  value

Comment: Unrelated, but: when dealing with `date` values, you can also use simple integers, e.g. `current_date - 30` you don't need an `interval` to specify a number of days

Comment: So `current_date - ${p_active_data_days_interval}` should work.

Comment: For intervals other than days: `current_date - ${numeric_variable} * interval '1 hour'` (for example). See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've already tried Where systemmodstamp::date > (current_date - interval '${30 days}')::date. I'm able to pull the data with this query. But, I don't want to use hard coded 30 days in the interval. Instead, if i use the parameter I can define what active data is and set the value on my own

Comment: `'${p_active_data_days_interval} day'` is being interpreted as a literal string. That's why it does not work.

Comment: @unutbu '${p_active_data_days_interval} day')::date i'm representing the interval as a date